# CentOS 7 not detecting network interface controller

Tags: centos, networkmanager, nmcli

CentOS 7 minimal installed on a remote server. It has two NICs. Same setup as other servers I've handled. However, one of them doesn't appear to be working.

```
[root@home network-scripts]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:50:99:d3:10:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

[root@home network-scripts]# nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
enp4s0  ethernet  connected  enp4s0
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

And yet, there's files for both `ifcfg-enp4s0` and `ifcfg-eno1` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

This is `ifcfg-eno1`:

```
# Generated by dracut initrd
NAME=eno1
DEVICE=eno1
ONBOOT=yes
NETBOOT=yes
UUID=912a3ac8-03b8-418c-9dd1-f0376d996d51
IPV6INIT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
```

And when I run:

```
[root@home network-scripts]# ifup eno1
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

The output of

`[root@home network-scripts]# lshw -class network`

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: d0:50:99:d3:10:2c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=3.16, 0x800004d6 ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:a1100000-a117ffff ioport:3000(size=32) memory:a1180000-a1183fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 10
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a1300000-a131ffff
```

I'm not sure what `UNCLAIMED` above means.

I've also tried checking the kernel output:

```
[root@home network-scripts]# dmesg | grep -i "Network Connection"
[    2.488019] igb 0000:04:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
```

And some `lspci` output:

```
[root@home net]# lspci | grep Connection
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

I am not quite sure if this is a driver issue (following this [FAQ](http://elrepo.org/tiki/FAQ), but based on the output below, both devices have the appropriate driver installed:

```
[root@home network-scripts]# /sbin/lspci -nn | grep -i net
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM [8086:15bb] (rev 10)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1533] (rev 03)

[root@home network-scripts]# for BUSID in $(/sbin/lspci | awk '{ IGNORECASE=1 } /net/ { print $1 }'); do /sbin/lspci -s $BUSID -m; /sbin/lspci -s $BUSID -n; done
00:1f.6 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM" -r10 "ASRock Incorporation" "Device 15bb"
00:1f.6 0200: 8086:15bb (rev 10)
04:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I210 Gigabit Network Connection" -r03 "ASRock Incorporation" "Device 1533"
04:00.0 0200: 8086:1533 (rev 03)

[root@home network-scripts]# grep -i 8086 /lib/modules/*/modules.alias | grep -i 1533
/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64/modules.alias:alias pci:v00008086d00001533sv*sd*bc*sc*i* igb
/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/modules.alias:alias pci:v00008086d00001533sv*sd*bc*sc*i* igb

[root@home network-scripts]# grep -i 8086 /lib/modules/*/modules.alias | grep -i 15bb
/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64/modules.alias:alias pci:v00008086d000015BBsv*sd*bc*sc*i* e1000e
/lib/modules/3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64/modules.alias:alias pci:v00008086d000015BBsv*sd*bc*sc*i* e1000e
```

How can I tell if I'm having a software issue here with the OS or a hardware issue with the physical port / motherboard?

Am I missing something entirely obvious?

Edit: Here is the relevant driver output from `lspci -k`:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 15bb
    Kernel modules: e1000e
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device 1533
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb`
```

Comment: First, check which kernel drivers are used by the hardware (`lspci -k`) then make sure the drivers are loaded.  I wouldn't worry about the `modules.alias` file as that has nothing to do with your hardware (it's just a generic mapping file).  Generally, with Intel NICs it's not going to be a driver issue as the driver and firmware is shipped with the kernel.

Start by configuring the NIC by hand with `ip link` & `ip addr`, that will ensure that the card is in working order.  Then, if you can pass packets, move onto NetworkManager.

Comment: @BrianRedbeard I've updated my original post with the output. It seems like I am missing a driver for `Device 15bb`. However, I can't find anything for `15bb` in the DeviceIDs: http://elrepo.org/tiki/DeviceIDs, although I do see `1533`.

Comment: I am seeing on other functional devices that `Device 15bb` are fully showing `Kernel driver in use: e1000e`.

Answer (score -1):

eno1 does not look correct...
that is not how centos7 names interfaces...

should look something like this:

```
lshw -class network

  *-network:0 DISABLED      
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:15:00.0
       logical name: ens5f0
       version: 01
       serial: 90:e2:ba:84:cd:5c
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.1.0-k-rh7.7 firmware=0x000161ab latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=fibre
       resources: irq:44 memory:fbf80000-fbffffff ioport:5000(size=32) memory:fbf70000-fbf73fff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:15:00.1
       logical name: ens5f1
       version: 01
       serial: 90:e2:ba:84:cd:5d
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=5.1.0-k-rh7.7 firmware=0x000161ab latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=fibre
       resources: irq:70 memory:fbe80000-fbefffff ioport:5020(size=32) memory:fbe70000-fbe73fff
```

Comment: You don't really address any of the issues in the question.